# Problem in creating two Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

HI i m trying to create virtual hosts for my PHP sites.I edited httpd-vhosts.conf with the following code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
 DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/logo
 ServerName localhost
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>  
 DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/new
 ServerName local
 </VirtualHost>
```

and host file with

```
127.0.0.1       local
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Now the logo project is accessible but the new is not.

Comment: If you could post your entire virtual host configs, then we might be able to help you more, but now I think there's not enough information.

Comment: Can you post the entire <VirtualHost> section for each virtual host?

Comment: He did, it was just lost in the formatting ;)

Comment: did you restart the apache server?

Comment: `<VirtualHost *:80>  
 DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/logosnap
 ServerName localhost
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>  
 DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/new
 ServerName local
 </VirtualHost>`

Comment: Yes i did restart...

Answer (score 2):

When you write `<VirtualHost *:80>` you are telling Apache to listen in **any** ip address regardless the ServerName.

What you have to do it's put the ServerName instead of `*`, like this:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>  
 DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/logo
 ServerName localhost
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost local:80>  
 DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/new
 ServerName local
 </VirtualHost>
```

This is because the ServerName is in the HTTP header.

Answer (score 0):

i think you cannot use local as virtualname, try something like 
local.de or dev.de I don't know, but at least with one point in it.

I believe the only exception to that is localhost.

also don't forgot to restart the apache server when you change the config file

**EDIT:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
 DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/logo
 ServerName localhost
 ServerAlias localhost
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>  
 DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/new
 ServerName dev.com
 ServerAlias dev.com
 </VirtualHost>
```

try this, this is how I use it

Comment: dev.de also opens logosnap

Comment: Can you try your public IP instead of the localhost ip? Maybe Apache has some special handling for the '127.0.0.1'

Answer (score 0):

```
NameVirtualHost localhost
<VirtualHost localhost>  
 DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/logo
 ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost local
<VirtualHost local>  
 DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/new
 ServerName local
</VirtualHost>
```

I would try this.